# python check if dictionaries value of a key duplicate in list

Tags: python

I have a set of data, and I want to check if the `value` in my `data` are duplicates.
My method is below, and I think it's a bit complicated, so I want to ask is there a better way to do this ?

```
data =[
        {"name": "ali", 
         "value": "ABC" 
         },
        {"name": "bob", 
         "value": "ABC" 
         },
        {"name": "cathy", 
         "value": "ABC" 
         },
        {"name": "david", 
         "value": "ABCD" 
         },
    ]


check_list = []
duplicate_value = []
for d in data:
    if d["value"] not in check_list:
        check_list.append(d["value"]) 
    else:
        if d["value"] not in duplicate_value:
            duplicate_value.append(d["value"])


print  "You have duplicate value:", duplicate_value
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `set` of `(key, value)` entries?

Comment: He seems only interested in duplicates in values. `set([('ali', 'ABC'), ('bob', 'ABC')])` doesn't really help much here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

data =[
        {"name": "ali", 
         "value": "ABC" 
         },
        {"name": "bob", 
         "value": "ABC" 
         },
        {"name": "cathy", 
         "value": "ABC" 
         },
        {"name": "david", 
         "value": "ABCD" 
         },
    ]

arr = [d['value'] for d in data]

duplicate_values = [k for k, v in Counter(arr).items() if v > 1]

print('Duplicate values - ', duplicate_values)
```

Output -

```
Duplicate values -  ['ABC']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple as:

```
def has_duplicates(your_list):
    values = [item['value'] for item in your_list]

    return len(set(values)) < len(values)

def get_duplicates(your_list):
    values = [item['value'] for item in some_list]

    return [item for item in set(values) if values.count(item) > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> c = collections.Counter(d['value'] for d in data)
>>> c
Counter({'ABC': 3, 'ABCD': 1})
>>> duplicates = [k for k, n in c.most_common() if n > 1]
>>> duplicates
['ABC']
```