# Check if there are duplicate values in list of dictionaries and update said duplicate values

Tags: python, list

I have a list of dictionaries that look like this:

```
[{'id' : '3412' , 'value' : 'x'} , {'id' : '5618' , 'value' : 'y'} , {'id' : '3412' , 'value' : 'z'}]
```

I need to find out if there are duplicate ids and replace any one of the duplicate id with a randomly generated 4-digit id that does not exist in the list. For example in the above scenario I need to change the id of either the first or third dict so that for example the list may look like:

```
[{'id' : '3412' , 'value' : 'x'} , {'id' : '5618' , 'value' : 'y'} , {'id' : '6123' , 'value' : 'z'}]
```

I can find if there are duplicate values in the list using [python check if dictionaries value of a key duplicate in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348075/python-check-if-dictionaries-value-of-a-key-duplicate-in-list) but is there an efficient way to update the dict values?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any detail on your attempt, here's what I will do at such scenarios:

```
from random import randint

dict = [{'id': '3412', 'value': 'x'}, {'id': '5618', 'value': 'y'}, {'id': '3412', 'value': 'z'}]


def random_int():
    return str(randint(1000, 9999))

temp = set()
for elem in dict:
    if elem['id'] in temp:
        elem['id'] = random_int()
        temp.add(elem['id'])
    else:
        temp.add(elem['id'])
print(dict)
# [{'id': '3412', 'value': 'x'}, {'id': '5618', 'value': 'y'}, {'id': '1879', 'value': 'z'}]
```

There's a small probability that randint can generate a number already in the dict, for that you can create another conditional loop if you want.

Comment: how can you be so sure that you wont get the same number using random_int()

Comment: @Manoj thats what i said in the last line? the main purpose of this SO question was to know how to edit the value. NOT the entire code.

Comment: sorry my bad. didn't notice the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @Neeraj answered. you can prevent duplicates from reoccuring in random_int() like this.

```
def random_int(temp):
     val=str(randint(1000, 9999))
     if(val in temp):
         random_int(temp)
     else:
         return val
```